# corrupt url for spring handler

Tags: spring, url, parameters

i have such redirect within my javascript:

> window.location.href = '/webapp/record.action?date='+varDate+'&id=' +
>   varId;

When i execute this, i invoke my spring-handler as expected:

```
public void record(Model model, @RequestParam(value="varDate") String date, @RequestParam(value="varId",) String id){...}
```

But my second parameter "varId" is everytime null. When i'am looking on my HttpServletRequest i see instead of shown url this url:

> /webapp/record.action?varDate=2017-07-01&_=1500358872039)@1495183143
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request@591eaf27

How this url has been created? Why i lost second parameter "varId" ?

Answer (score 0):

you are passing the parameter as **id** and in spring controller you are trying to retrieve it as **varId**.

change you code in controller as below:

```
public void record(Model model, @RequestParam(value="varDate") String date, @RequestParam(value="id",) String id){
  // your custom logic

}
```